# Use of Rust alignment feature (issue 33626)

Tags: rust, memory-alignment

[RFC 1358](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1358-repr-align.md) suggested an alignment attribute `#[repr(align="N")]` and it was accepted. [Rust issue 33626](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/33626) incorporated the feature into the nightly version.

I'm unable to use this feature with `rustc 1.19.0-nightly (777ee2079 2017-05-01)`. If I compile *without* the feature gate (`#![feature(repr_align)]`):

```
#[repr(align="16")]
struct Foo {
    bar: u32,
}
```

I get the following error statement:

```
error: the struct `#[repr(align(u16))]` attribute is experimental (see issue #33626)
 --> foo.rs:3:1
  |
3 | / struct Foo {
4 | |     bar: u32,
5 | | }
  | |_^
  |
  = help: add #![feature(repr_align)] to the crate attributes to enable
```

When I compile *with* the feature gate, the error message says:

```
error[E0552]: unrecognized representation hint
 --> foo.rs:3:8
  |
3 | #[repr(align="16")]
  |        ^^^^^^^^^^
```

I also tried the version suggested by the first error message (even though it does not comply with the issue), but still without success. What is the correct way to use the alignment feature?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can make that feature work when combined with
 [attribute literals](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/6a46363a22fdf6c2a4f49d36862a7e15851ccef4/text/1559-attributes-with-literals.md) ([Playground](https://play.integer32.com/?gist=57937e012f199cba90e20cc77c8adf05&version=undefined)):

```
#![feature(repr_align)]
#![feature(attr_literals)]

#[repr(align(16))]
struct Foo {
    bar: u32,
}
```

This is known to work in the latest development version ([PR #41673](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/41673)). Searching ["repr align"](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/search?l=Rust&q=repr+align&type=&utf8=%E2%9C%93) in the Rust compiler's codebase, 
all occurrences rely on attribute literals, so it seems likely that the documented form `repr(align="N")` is not yet supported.

Comment: I much prefer the new syntax, but it certainly is tricky when there's no hint that the "documented" syntax is actually not supported.